# Using Vue, Inertia, Laravel, how do I update a file object in an edit component?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I currently have an edit page, which hits an update function to update the Itinerary object when changed.

On this page, if I click submit straight away, and dd() the $request from the ItineraryController, it returns all of the existing form data, as expected.

If I edit the data in the fields, then submit it, it returns successfully with a full request object as expected.

If, however, I choose a file in the "replace file" selector, the entire request object shows as null when the form is submitted, and thus can't be submitted.

How can I adjust this so that the "replace file" input is operational, and fills the request object with the existing itinerary data?

Component:

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submit">
    <div class="row w-75 m-auto">
      <h1>Edit Itinerary</h1>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input v-model="form.title" class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Itinerary Title" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row w-75 m-auto">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="gen_narrative">Narrative</label>
        <textarea v-model="form.gen_narrative" class="form-control" name="gen_narrative" placeholder="Itinerary Narrative"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row w-75 m-auto">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Current Photo</label>
        <img :src="assetUrl(props.itinerary.f_photo)" alt="featured photo" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="row w-75 m-auto">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="f_photo">Replace Photo</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="f_photo" type="file" @input="fileChange" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row w-75 m-auto">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label for="authorid">Author Name</label>
        <input v-model="form.authorid" class="form-control" name="authorid" placeholder="Author Name" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row w-75 m-auto">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Edit Itinerary</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script setup>
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

function assetUrl(path) {
  return process.env.MIX_BASE_URL + "storage/" + path;
}

function fileChange(event) {
  form.f_photo = event.target.files[0];
}

let props = defineProps({
  itinerary: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
});

let form = useForm({
  title: props.itinerary.title,
  gen_narrative: props.itinerary.gen_narrative,
  f_photo: null,
  authorid: props.itinerary.authorid,
  stops: props.itinerary.stops,
});
let submit = () => {
  console.log(form.title);
  form.patch("/itineraries/" + props.itinerary.id);
  form.reset();
};
console.log(form);
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Controller:

```
 public function edit($id)
{
    $itinerary = Itinerary::find($id);
    return Inertia::render('Itineraries/Edit', [
        'itinerary' => $itinerary,
    ]);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $itinerary = Itinerary::find($id);
    $itinerary->title = $request->title;
    $itinerary->gen_narrative = $request->gen_narrative;
    //upload the photo
    if ($request->hasFile('f_photo')) {
        $itinerary->f_photo = $request->f_photo->store('public/itinerary_photos');
    }
    $itinerary->authorid = $request->authorid;
    $itinerary->save();

    return redirect('/itineraries');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let form = useForm({
    forceFormData: true,
    title: props.itinerary.title,
    gen_narrative: props.itinerary.gen_narrative,
    f_photo: null,
    authorid: props.itinerary.authorid,
    stops: props.itinerary.stops
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably because Inertia does not natively support uploading files using a multipart/form-data request for the put, patch or delete methods, as is stated [here](https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads) (in the "Multipart limitations" section).

An alternative way is to submit without form helper using post method with the _method attribute of 'put', like:

```
Inertia.post("/itineraries/" + props.itinerary.id", {
    _method: 'put',
    f_photo: form.f_photo,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with is writing your file upload inline

```
        <div class="row w-75 m-auto">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="f_photo">Replace Photo</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="f_photo" type="file" @input="form.f_photo = event.target.files[0]"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [example](https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads#file-upload-example) in official documentation you can do

```html
<input type="file" @input="form.f_photo = $event.target.files[0]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Inertia form helper to upload files, you need to add _method: 'patch' or 'put' like this:

```
const form = useForm({
    _method: 'patch',
    your code
});

and then

const handleFileChange = () => {
    form.image = fileInput.value.files[0];
    form.post(route('resource.update'),{
        preserveScroll: true,
    });
 

<input @change="handleFileChange" ref="fileInput" id="image" type="file" name="image" />

};
```